# Pass multiple parameters to powershell file through Process.Start

Tags: c#, powershell, process.start

I'm having an issue on passing multiple parameters for a powershell file to run through Process.Start. This is what I have so far

```
                    strCmdText = "/c powershell.exe -file " + filePath + " " + configs[i].name + " " + configs[i].path + "/" + configs[i].extension + " " + configs[i].value;
                System.Diagnostics.Process pro = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("cmd.exe", strCmdText);
```

I've found many examples that would demonstrate how to execute a powershell file through this but never any one that had multiple parameters, I assumed it'd be something like this but the command isn't working properly.

Comment: You use Start Info.  The command line is one string like -a -b -c.  then in the power shell it is the same as running from command window with parameters having a dollar sign.

Comment: Why are you executing `powershell.exe` using `cmd.exe`? Why not just run `powershell.exe` directly?

Comment: did you try the -file flag after your args instead of before?

Comment: what is your filepath? a script powershell ? if its a powershell script could you show the beginning of script with the definition of param